Инициализировать словарь в пакете вне функции(syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body)
Я хочу инициализировать глоабльный словарь в пакете(примерно как статик переменную в с++, которая до исполнения программы создастся и положется в отдельную область памяти ), но насколько я понимаю, из пакета могут выполняться только функции, которые мы вызвали, что-то другое в пакетет писать запрещено(?)
я пробовал вот как:
var commits map[string]int
commits = map[string]int{
    "rsc": 3711,
    "r":   2138,
    "gri": 1908,
    "adg": 912,
}

Но видимо , в силу того, что надо выполнить эту операцию присваивания, вне функции так писать нельзя, ошибка
syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body

как решить данную проблему?
UPD:
Придумал так:
func ConstCommitDictFunc() map[string]int{
return map[string]int{
    "rsc": 3711,
    "r":   2138,
    "gri": 1908,
    "adg": 912,
}
}


Зачем вам присваивание отдельно?
var commits = map[string]int{
    "rsc": 3711,
    "r":   2138,
    "gri": 1908,
    "adg": 912,
}

https://go.dev/play/p/_VUuwYfSyiB
